# why does HiveContext in spark-shell give wrong config value

Tags: apache-spark, hive, apache-spark-sql

In spark-shell the HiveContext has wrong "hive.metastore.warehouse.dir" .

I have set `hive-site.xml` and I have checked it is read by `getConf("my.conf.test")`

```
<property>
  <name>hive.metastore.warehouse.dir</name>
  <value>/user/hive/warehouse</value>
</property>
<property>
  <name>hive.conf.test</name>
  <value>yes</value>
</property>
```

.

```
scala> sqlContext.getConf("hive.conf.test")
res3: String = yes
```

But for metastore dir conf, it give me not what I have set in hive-site.

```
scala> sqlContext.getConf("hive.metastore.warehouse.dir")
res3: String = file:/tmp/spark-7ff284bc-4b1b-400f-8bc4-2f8a97d86399/metastore
```

Even I set `metastore.warehouse.dir` wrongly, it should give a default value `/user/hive/warehouse`  but not `/tmp/.........`.

Comment: can you try setting those properties for when you start the spark-shell ?

Comment: May sound silly, but have you copied your hive-site.xml to spark configuration directory yet? If yes, have you checked it there. If no, then copy it there and restart spark.

Comment: yes, I have my config in spark/conf and  checked in spark-shell.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same issue. My solution is 
new a hiveConf which will automatically load hive-site.xml

```
val hiveConf = new HiveConf()
hiveConf.get("hive.metastore.warehouse.dir")
```